# flutter_web_auth doesn't redirect from WebView to the app after authorizing the access to my data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, web, oauth-2.0, flutter-android

First of all, I'm trying to get an authorization code by authenticating my account to my app.
To do this I used this package [flutter_web_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth).
After implementing all what's described on the page of the package , and opening the WebView to authorize my app to access my account data, I don't get redirected to the app from WebView, here are the changes I made to `AndroidManifest.xml` and my code:

`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
   <application
        android:label="swiftycompanion"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
        ( SOME CODE I HIDDEN THAT COME WITH THE INITIAL APP TO SIMPLIFY THE CODE )
        </activity>
       <activity
           android:exported="true"
           android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity">
           <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
               <data android:scheme="com.example.swiftycompanion://redirect" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
```

And here is my code:

```
Future getAccessTokenWithAuthorizationCodeFlow() async {
  String url = 'https://api.intra.fr/oauth/authorize'
      '?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'
      '&redirect_uri=com.example.swiftycompanion%3A%2F%2Fredirect'
      '&response_type=code';
  try {
    final String result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
      url: url,
      callbackUrlScheme: 'com.example.swiftycompanion://redirect'
    );
    final String? token = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['token'];
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same package, as android:scheme just add your package name without the ://redirect in the end.

Please, see the example below:

```
<intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="com.example.swifty_companion" />
       </intent-filter>
```