# Flutter flutter_web_auth after authorization, I don't get redirected to my app with callbackUrlScheme https

Tags: flutter

I am a newbie in flutter and I am using visual studio code for my development. I have been tasked by my company to implement  oauth2 in flutter for one of our
clients. I have read the implementation guide on flutter_web_auth through this link https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth_2 and the possible cause of not
being redirected back to your app after authorization on stack overflow. None seems to work for me.

After authorization, I don't get redirected to my  app hence no Authorization Code Grant Response. I've spent close to 2 days I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.
The value in my callbackUrlScheme is 'https'

**redirect_uri** is **https://example.com/api/external/client/hybridflow/callback**

**Please  note: I am just using example.com in place of the real domain name or host .**

and my AndroidManifest.xml containing verified Applink status below

```
<activity  android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth_2.CallbackActivity" android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth_2" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/api/external/client/hybridflow/callback" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**And here is my code**

```
class ExternalClientOauthService {
  var logger = Logger(
    filter: null,
    printer: PrettyPrinter(),
    output: null,
  );

  Future<String> getExternalClientAuthorizationAsync(
      String signedauthorizeRequestUrl,
      [String oauthCallbackUrlScheme = '']) async {
    try {
      final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
        url: signedauthorizeRequestUrl,
        callbackUrlScheme: oauthCallbackUrlScheme,
      );
 
      return result;
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
      rethrow;
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
      rethrow;
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
      rethrow;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
      rethrow;
    } finally {}
  }
}

 Future<String> _getAuthorizationAsync(String signAuthorizeRequestUrl,
      [String customCallbackUrlScheme = '']) {
    var aouthRequest = _oauthExternalService.getExternalClientAuthorizationAsync(
        signAuthorizeRequestUrl, customCallbackUrlScheme);
    return aouthRequest;
  }
```

```
    String url = 'https://api.xxxx.com/oauth/authorize'
      '?client_id=xxxxxx'
      '&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2Fexternal%2Fclient%2Fhybridflow%2Fcallback'
      '&response_type=code';

var authorizeurl = Uri.parse(url).toString();
 var authorizationCodGrantResponse =
                    await _getAuthorizationAsync(authorizeurl,
                        'https');
```

**The code above is called here below**

Possible cause of not being redirected back to your app after authorization on stack overflow. None of the solutions in the links below work for me.

[flutter_web_auth doesn't redirect from WebView to the app after authorizing the access to my data in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453841/flutter-web-auth-doesnt-redirect-from-webview-to-the-app-after-authorizing-the)

[Use Android App Link as an OAuth2 Redirect URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287268/use-android-app-link-as-an-oauth2-redirect-uri)

Comment: I have resolved the issue I'm facing by adding queries tag on top of my Application in AndroidManifest.xml file for https and http scheme. see below <queries> <intent> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <data android:scheme="https" /> </intent> <intent> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" /> </intent> </queries>